# jquery show/hide multiple div toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

First of all thanks for taking your time to help me with this.

Sorry for my english ;-)

Well i give you a link to my project it will be more easier to understand my problem

http://lix.in/-c20b94

As you can see on the right side, you have social panels.

I wanted with jquery to open a panel for each one (with last feeds). After reading some posts here i was able to make it working ( i am not really good at jquery). But i still have a problem.

As you can notice when you click on another button (facebook, youtube...) panels switch off/on etc.. but the button by itself stay in active position. it don't come back at his normal position. I think it due to a toggle problem

CODE:

```
$(".link1").click(function(){
    $("#twittercontent, #youtubehome").hide();
    $("#pz_fbplugin").toggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    return false;
    $(".link2, .link3").removeClass('active');
    $(".link1").addClass("active");
});

$(".link2").click(function(){
    $("#pz_fbplugin, #youtubehome").hide();
    $("#twittercontent").toggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
        return false;
    $(".link1, .link3").removeClass("active");
    $(".link2").addClass("active");
});

$(".link3").click(function(){
    $("#pz_fbplugin, #twittercontent").hide();
    $("#youtubehome").toggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    return false;
    $(".link1, .link2").removeClass("active");
    $(".link3").addClass("active");
});
```

CSS:

```
a.facebook {width: 46px;position: fixed; right:0;  height: 130px; top: 175px; margin-right: 0; background: url("socialrudyfacebook.png")no-repeat; z-index:51}
a.facebook:hover{width: 129px}
a.active.facebook{width: 129px}

a.twitter{width: 46px; position: fixed; height: 130px;right: 0; top: 317px; margin-right: 0;z-index: 51;background: url("socialrudytwitter.png")no-repeat; a-index:51}
a.twitter:hover{ width: 129px}
a.active.twitter{ width: 129px}

a.youtube{width: 46px;position: fixed; height: 130px; right: 0; top: 457px ;z-index: 150; background: url("socialrudyyoutube")no-repeat; a-index:51}
a.youtube:hover{ width: 129px}
a.active.youtube{ width: 129px}
```

Hope it's enaugh for you to help me with this.

Comment: In all cases you have `return false;` prior to manipulating your classes, so those changes do not get executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the `return false`. If you remove it or move it down, it should work. Instead of return you can also use:

```
$(".link3").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // your function and stuff
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much  a little mistake who make the difference ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you `return false` the rest of the code is not excecuted. Remote it and it'll works, or just to make things simple do the following.

Add the same class to each link. Like "tab".

Then on each .click that you have there just call.

```
$('.tab').removeClass("active");
```

And when you click on a tab, you'll make sure the rest go back to the original state.

```
if ($(this).hasClass('active'))
    $(this).removeClass('active');
```

Add that line to each .click and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Move `return false` to the end of function. This is must help.